# Get ul li a string values and store them in a variable or array php

Tags: php, html, string, dom, getelementsbyclassname

Im trying to store the string value's of a list item on my website into a variable/array in PHP to do some conditional checks/statements with them. Am having a bit off difficulty getting the list item's string value using PHP, can anybody help?

This is the markup.

```
<div class="coursesListed">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><h3>Item one</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h3>item two</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h3>Item three</h3></a></li>            
</ul>
</div>
```

What i want ideally is either a variable or array that holds the values "Item one", "Item two", "Item three".

Comment: Well for a start, PHP works on a `name` attribute. So you might want to give your elements one of those :)

Comment: Are you trying to parse the HTML and retrieve the values in all the <h3> tags?

Comment: You can do that with some JS + PHP.

Comment: Okay I can give them a name. Amal, you will have to excuse my ignorance, im fairly new to programming in PHP. Yes im trying to retrive the values in the H3 tags, but only the H3 tags in the class coursesListed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @RoseCoder: Please make yourself comfortable about which kind of questions are valid to be asked. For example, in that general form, you should first look for existing material like [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456) and then let us know into which problems you ran into with that (if even any problem). Because each other user with a different website to parse could ask a new question then which does not turn out well. Thanks for taking care!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$html = '<div class="coursesListed">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><h3>Item one</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h3>item two</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h3>Item three</h3></a></li>            
</ul>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$liList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
$liValues = array();
foreach ($liList as $li) {
    $liValues[] = $li->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($liValues);
```

Comment: Its working fine for me, online output link http://codepad.org/VyLj8cU0

Comment: This works great, is there anyway of dynamically retrieving whats stored int he $html variable without declaring it like that? Many thanks

Comment: Yes pass the dynamic string to `loadHTML` like `$doc->loadHTML($dynamic_string);`

Comment: @ManojYadav one more thing, what if i also want to get the `href` attribute of every `<li>` tag? Please help.

Comment: @Ali use `DOMElement::getAttribute function` to get a attribute value. http://in3.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php and I think you mean how to get `href` of `a` tag not `li` tag

Comment: Yes Manoj, i meant to say that i have a `ul` of almost 65 `li` and every `li` has a link upon it. So what i want to do is to get only first 5 `li` in an array (along with the associated link) and print them along with the `href` associated with their respective `li`. Hope you get it :)

Comment: To get `href` of `a` in `li` try this `$li->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')` or if `href` in `li` then try this `$li->getAttribute('href')`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse the HTML code get the text out. DOM parser can be used for this purpose.

```
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str); // $str is your HTML code as a string

   //get all H3 
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h3');
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to parse it in Javascript (perhaps using jQuery), and then send it to your PHP with some AJAX.

```js
// Javascript/jQuery
var array = [];
$("h3").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).html());
});

var message = JSON.stringify(array);
$.post('test.php', {data: message}, function(data) {
    document.write(data); // "success"
}
```

Then in PHP:

```php
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];

// convert json into array
$array = json_decode($data);

// do stuff with your data
// then send back whatever you need

echo "success";

?>
```