# how can I get the value by tagnames in php?

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

could you give a suggestion to my code , please ?

```
$string = "<li>CIs = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.pdomhp?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=49&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::49">Sep Console04</a>, 42 49, Sep11, Sep Console04<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=50&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::50">Sep Console05</a>, 42 50, Sep11, Sep Console05<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=53&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::53">Sep Engine CO04</a>, 42 53, Sep11, Sep Engine CO04</li>";
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHtml($string);
$result_data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
```

But, I couldn't get the correct result . thanks all of you !

Best regards,

Anwar

Comment: What are you getting and what is the expected result? Are you getting any error? (cause I suspect you are indeed getting a parser error)

Comment: yes, you are right . I got the following error message: " Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string " thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're really close

The following will do the trick:

```
$string = '<li>CIs = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.pdomhp?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=49&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::49">Sep Console04</a>, 42 49, Sep11, Sep Console04<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=50&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::50">Sep Console05</a>, 42 50, Sep11, Sep Console05<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=53&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::53">Sep Engine CO04</a>, 42 53, Sep11, Sep Engine CO04</li>';
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHtml($string);
$liList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
$result_data = array();
foreach ($liList as $li) {
    $result_data[] = $li->nodeValue;
}
```

see: [Get ul li a string values and store them in a variable or array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638165/get-ul-li-a-string-values-and-store-them-in-a-variable-or-array-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes before `<li>` and after `</li>`

Also change all `&` to `&amp;` in your string, they are special characters that need to be converted to HTML:

```
$string = str_replace('&','&amp;', $string);
```

Comment: I couldn't get your mean. could you explain with more detail , please ? thanks !